# nginx returns 405 on adding an empty if to a location block

Tags: nginx, configuration, http

Assume we have the following config (`$branch` is set before this snippet, but it's not related, I guess):

```
# If the request origin ends in .domain.com
set $allowed_origin "";
if ($http_origin ~* ^(.+\.)?domain\.com$) {
  set $allowed_origin $http_origin;
}

add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "$allowed_origin" always;
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true" always;
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Accept, Authorization, Content-Type, Cookie, Some-Custom-Header, Another-Custom-Header, X-And-Another-One" always;
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, OPTIONS" always;

root /var/path/www/$branch/www;
index index.php index.html;
error_page 404 = /notfound.php;

location ~ ^/v\d+/ {
  root /var/path/www/$branch/www;
  try_files $uri_lower $uri_lower/ /some.php?$query_string;
}

location / {
  root /var/path/www/$branch/www;
  try_files $uri_lower $uri_lower/ =404;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
  try_files $uri_lower $uri_lower/ $uri $uri/ =404;
  include fastcgi-params;
}
```

This works fine (returns 200) for the following request:

```
OPTIONS https://some.domain.com/v1/graphql HTTP/1.1
Host: some.domain.com
Origin: https://another.domain.com
```

However, when I just add an empty `if` (no `add_header` modifications, just an empty `if`) into the first `location` making it:

```
location ~ ^/v\d+/ {
  if ($http_origin ~* ^(.+\.)?domain\.com$) {
  }
  root /var/path/www/$branch/www;
  try_files $uri_lower $uri_lower/ /some.php?$query_string;
}
```

it starts responding with

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Not Allowed
```

Does anyone know why and how I can add an if condition here. Potentially, I'd like to manipulate headers inside this if setting certain CORS one only for allowed origin.

Comment: You have effectively bypassed the `try_files` statement, so the request is no longer being processed by `some.php`. See [this document](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of an `if` block inside a `location` block.

Comment: Thanks Richard! I think I'll need to create two conditions making it early return 200 only for OPTIONS request type (and conditions like described here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/conditional-within-an-if-in-nginx ) and only for whitelisted origins. Just to make sure I don't do an early 200 return for non-options requests. That's the only solution I can think of now